# Searching and matching in data frames

Tags: r, distance, dataframe

I am very new to `R` so forgive me if this is extremely basic question. Using the instructions below I edited the question to hopefully make more sense.

I have a data frame `d` that looks like this

```
SAMPLE <-c("blueberry", "broccoli")
OPT1 <-c("apple", "beef")
OPT2 <-c("oatmeal", "bacon")
RESPONSE <- c("oatmeal", "beef")
d <- data.frame(SAMPLE,OPT1,OPT2, RESPONSE)
```

add column of NA for new data

```
d$OPT1.D <- rep("NA",nrow(d));
```

and distance matrix `dist`

```
X <-c("blueberry", "beef", "oatmeal", "broccoli")
blueberry <-c("0", "0.17", "0.09", "0.21")
beef <-c("0.15", "0", "0.979", "0.75")
oatmeal <- c("0.09", "0.375", "0", "0.71")
broccoli <- c("0.25", "0.671", "0.45", "0")
dist <- data.frame(X,blueberry,beef, oatmeal, broccoli)
```

So I want to find row/column match in `dist` for `d$RESPONSE` and `d$SAMPLE`. In new column for `d$OPT1.D`, the first entry should be `0.09`, which is distance between 'oatmeal' and "blueberry" in `dist`. Second entry should be `0.671`, distance between "beef" and "broccoli".

Hope this makes more sense? I used the code below, `d$OPT1.D <- dist[cbind(d$RESPONSE, d$SAMPLE)]` but it returned text, not number. Many thanks.

Overall this seems like should be a fairly straightforward operation but after searching for a bit I can't tell if this is best done by a FOR loop or package like data.table. Advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is tailor-built for matrix indexing, a little-known but very powerful feature of R.  All you need is this command (and then repeat for OPT2).

```
d$OPT1D <- dist[cbind(d$RESPONSE, d$OPT1)]
```

By the way, it is helpful to include your data in a way that others can easily read it in.  Here's what I did to get it.

```
d <- read.table(text="SAMPLE        OPT1        OPT2        RESPONSE        OPT1D        OPT2D
banana        blueberry   oatmeal     oatmeal         NA           NA
broccoli      beef        bacon       beef            NA           NA",
                 header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dist <- read.table(text="blueberry      beef           oatmeal
0              0.15           0.09
0.17           0              0.0872
0.09           0.0979         0", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dist <- as.matrix(dist)
rownames(dist) <- colnames(dist)



> d
    SAMPLE      OPT1    OPT2 RESPONSE OPT1D OPT2D
1   banana blueberry oatmeal  oatmeal  0.09    NA
2 broccoli      beef   bacon     beef  0.00    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that the types of d are factors, which are converted to integers (and not characters) when you try to use it as indices in dist[cbind(d$RESPONSE, d$OPT1)]. You need to use stringsAsFactors = FALSE when you call data.frame.

```
d <- data.frame(SAMPLE,OPT1,OPT2, RESPONSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The second problem is that dist is a data.frame, and it has no row names. Also, you don't need X to be a column.

```
dist <- cbind(blueberry,beef, oatmeal, broccoli)
rownames(dist) <- colnames(dist) <- X
```

Like this it should do what you want.

```
dist[cbind(d$RESPONSE, d$SAMPLE)]
[1] 0.090 0.671
```

Comment: also note that your distance matrix is not symmetric, which is a bit suspicious.

And as a matter of practice on this site, you should use the comments to communicate with the people that answer. If you realize that your question is not clear enough, you should edit your question. But you should not post an answer to re-ask you question.